# Keeping rackspace vserver alive

Tags: monitoring, virtualhost, keepalive

It appears to me that rackspace somehow freezes cloud VMs after some idle time. This means the first page request to a php page takes much longer to respond than the subsequent requests.

This is in some cases good, in other cases not acceptable.

I am actually querying a machine with wget from a different host now to keep it "alive". But I wonder what frequency would be necessary. Does anyone know the time period after which they send a VM to "sleep"? I guess it would be some minutes.

EDIT: There is absolutely no caching involved on the php site.

It just recently moved from another vhost and there was never such latency on the first request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is causing this, you can use a free 'site monitoring' service such as [Alertfox](http://alertfox.com) for this - it will request a page from your site every x minutes, keeping everything 'spun-up'.

Might also be worth asking Rackspace if they know of any reason why this should be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt that rackspace would freeze a VM. I advice getting in touch with someone from support.

**Edit** Are you absolutely sure that the server is down? Are you sure it's not to do with whatever you are hosting on the site?